# this.emit() in an arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Trying to figure out how to do an arrow function while maintaining `this.emit()`. In gulp and ES6 I have a function like so:

```
gulp.src([paths.sass])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', function (e) {
      reportError(e);
      this.emit('end');
    }))
```

Notice the usage of this.emit('end'). Works great when I use a non arrow function, but the second I do:

```
gulp.src([paths.sass])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', (e) => {
      reportError(e);
      this.emit('end');
    }))
```

`this.emit('end')` is no longer available. How could I write that function using an arrow function and maintain the `this.emit()`

Comment: You can't, arrow functions don't have a `this`.

Comment: Arrow functions are bound to their surrounding context – same as `function (e) { }.bind(this)`. That binding can't be undone or altered afterwards.

Comment: Welcome to `this` sucks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

in arrow function of ECMAScript2015, `this` always referencing outside function, no runtime context.

meaing:

```
function out() {
  var name = "out"
  return function() {
    return function() {
      return function() {
        console.log(this.name)   // out
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- arrow function no Object `arguments`
- arrow function can't using `yield`
- arrow function can't initialized by `new`

Answer (score 0):

If the `on` method of the `sass()` returned object arranges to call the supplied function as a method of another object, and the function needs to pick up the value of the object it is called on, in order to call its `emit` method, use the `function` declaration.

Arrow functions avoid using
 `Function.prototype.bind` on the current `this` value of the defining context, by always using the defining context's `this` value inside the function. Another aspect of arrow functions is that they can't be used as constructors. Arrow functions **do not deprecate** function declarations and expressions and should only be considered "preferable" on a case by case basis.